# Expressing the four-momentum operator in terms of field operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, operators, momentum, dirac-delta-distributions

There are a series of problems in chapter 3 of the book *Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings* by Hatfield that lead to a proof of Lorentz invariance in the canonical formulation of scalar field theory. This question is a result of attempt at the first of them.

The four-momentum operator in QFT is defined by $$P^{\mu} = \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac 1 {2\omega_k}k^{\mu}a^{\dagger}(k)a(k).$$ We can express the annihilation operator $a(k)$ in terms of field operators via $$a(k) = \int d^3x e^{ik\cdot x}(\omega_k \varphi (x, t) + i \pi(x, t)),$$ and the creation operator is the conjugate of this. Now, upon inserting the above formula into the definition of $P^{\mu}$, I obtain the following expression: $$\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac 1 {2\omega_k} k^{\mu}[\int d^3x d^3x'e^{ik\cdot (x' - x)}(\omega_k^2\varphi (x,t) \varphi(x', t) + i \omega_k \varphi (x,t) \pi(x',t) - i\omega_k\pi(x, t)\varphi(x',t) +\pi(x,t)\pi(x',t))].$$ After getting to this point, I have been unable to simplify further. The exponential underneath the integral over $x, x'$ motivates me to try and find a delta function to get rid of one the position integrals, but the presence of the $k^{\mu}$ prevents me from doing so. If anyone could offer advice or help in further simplification of this integral, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What, exactly, are you after?

Comment: I stated what I was after in the question. I am seeking to simplify the expression further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplicity is subjective here. You are meant to *do* something with your expression.

Assuming your expression is correct, interchange the *k* and *x,x'* integrations, and trade the *k* for an *x* gradient,
$$P^\mu=\int d^3x d^3x'\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac 1 {2\omega_k} i\partial^{\mu}~~[e^{ik\cdot (x' - x)}\\ 
(\omega_k^2\varphi (x,t) \varphi(x', t) + i \omega_k \varphi (x,t) \pi(x',t) - i\omega_k\pi(x, t)\varphi(x',t) +\pi(x,t)\pi(x',t))].$$

You may now proceed with your original idea of collapsing one position integral in the terms that matter, the ones of zeroth order in $\omega_k$. Note you will use this expression to commute with $\varphi(y)$ next, to see how *that*  transforms under commutation with your momentum operator!

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was missing. Thanks for helping out.